# SQL query on table

Tags: sql

I have a table like the following

```
sl.no   Machine Id    date  status
```

I need to get the last status for each machine ID for each day.(Everyday each machine ID will have many entries .I need to get the last entry for that day for each machine ID)
Please help

Comment: Which RDBMS and version? MySQL 5.x? SQL Server 2012? ...? Some make it easy, some make it harder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will solve your issue

```
Select MachineID, Date,
   (Select Top 1 t1.Status
    FROM table As t1
    WHERE t1.MachineID = table.MachineID  
      AND t1.Date = table.Date
    order by slno desc)
FROM table
Group BY MachineID, Date
```

Comment: this will give me all entries on a particular date for each machine ID.My requirement is to get the last entry of each ID on each date